# Can session replication takes place without sticky session?

Tags: apache, tomcat, load-balancing, cluster-computing, session-replication

In the context of Tomcat, can session replication takes place without enabling sticky session?

I understand the purpose of sticky session is to have the client 'sticks' to 1 server throughout the session. With session replication, the client's interaction with the server is replicated throughout the cluster (many web servers).

In the above case, can session replication takes place? i.e. client's session is spread though out the web servers and each interaction with any one web server is replicated across, thus, allowing seamless interaction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, tomcat clustering does not support non-sticky sessions. From [tomcat docs](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/cluster-howto.html#Cluster_Basics):

> Make sure that your loadbalancer is configured for sticky session
>   mode.

But there's a solution (I created, so you know I'm biased :-)) called [memcached-session-manager](http://code.google.com/p/memcached-session-manager/) (msm), that also supports non-sticky sessions. msm uses [memcached](http://memcached.org/) (or any backend speaking the memcached protocol) as backend for session backup/storage.

In non-sticky mode sessions are only stored in memcached and no longer in tomcat, as with non-sticky sessions the session-store must be external (to avoid stale data).

It also supports session locking: with non-sticky sessions multiple, parallel requests may hit different tomcats and could modify the session in parallel, so that some of the session changes might get overwritten by others. Session locking allows synchronization of parallel requests going to different tomcats.

The [msm home page](http://code.google.com/p/memcached-session-manager/) mainly describes the sticky session approach (as it started with this only), for details regarding non-sticky sessions you might search or ask on the [mailing list](http://groups.google.com/group/memcached-session-manager).

Details and examples regarding the configuration can be found in the [msm wiki (SetupAndConfiguration)](http://code.google.com/p/memcached-session-manager/wiki/SetupAndConfiguration).

Just to give you an idea regarding the complexity: what you need is one or more [memcached](http://memcached.org/) servers running (or s.th. similar speaking memcached) and an updated tomcat context.xml like this:

```
<Context>
  ...
  <Manager className="de.javakaffee.web.msm.MemcachedBackupSessionManager"
    memcachedNodes="n1:host1.domain.com:11211,n2:host2.domain.com:11211"
    sticky="false"
    sessionBackupAsync="false"
    lockingMode="auto"
    requestUriIgnorePattern=".*\.(ico|png|gif|jpg|css|js)$"
    />
</Context>
```

Your load-balancer does not need special configuration, so once you have these things in place you can start testing your application.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I had read up Tomcat's FAQ but strangely, I am able to perform session replication without enabling sticky session on Tomcat mod_jk. Not sure if this is an abnormality.

Comment: Session replication itself works independently from the loadbalancer configuration. The issue should be, that several tomcats then share the same session leading to stale session data (assuming that you've no jvmRoute configured in tomcat). For example: if tomcat1 holds version 1 of session A (from first request), and tomcat2 holds version 2 of session A (as it changed it with request 2), and the 3rd request would go to tomcat 1 again, the changes from the 2nd request would be lost (session version 1 would be seen). *With* jvmRoute configured, you had a failover situation all the time...

Comment: Thanks for the insight Grotzke, provided much clarity on the question I asked. :)

Answer (score 0):

An excellent article about this topic here:

- http://www.mulesoft.com/tomcat-cluster

The terracotta product they mention has a simplistic tutorial here:

- http://www.terracotta.org/documentation/web-sessions/get-started

Terracotta works on Tomcat but you must pay attention to check which bits of Terracotta are free and which are commercial. A couple of years ago their redundant store was paid and I don't remember this solution being a separated product.

Comment: I had read the article but it does not address my question on whether can session replication takes place without sticky session. Application-wise for Tomcat, it is not possible to have session replication without first enabling sticky session.

Answer (score 0):

I have actually found the inverse to this question. Session replication for me (Tomcat7) with the OOTB options only works properly WITHOUT Sticky Session. After turning the logging up I found that with the JVMRoutes enabled my session ID goes from A123456789 to A123456789.01 -- suffixed with the jvmroute. That session is successfully replicated from Node 01 in the cluster to Node 02 but uses the same ID (A123456789.01). When I take Node 01 out of the cluster then the traffic starts to stick on Node 02 -- and it looks now for a session A123456789.02 which of course does not exist. .01 is there, but basically sits idle until it expires. If I bring the other server up and the sessions are replicated and then take 02 down, I get even odder behaviour because the session is picked up where it left off.

For me, so far, session replication without sticky sessions (just regular RR amongst the nodes in the cluster) is the only thing that has worked.